# TSQL select into insert multiple rows into 1 row, many columns simplest way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, pivot-table

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a results table that I wish to populate from data belonging from another table.

```
// Results table definition

create table resultsTable
(
  RowId int Identity(1,1) Not Null,

  sid1 int, colA1 int, colB1 int, colC1 int,
  sid2 int, colA2 int, colB2 int, colC2 int,
  sid3 int, colA3 int, colB3 int, colC3 int,
  colX  bit      
)

// Source table definition

create table sourceTable
(
  RowId int Identity(1,1) Not Null ,
  colA int , colB int , colC int , colX bit ,
)
```

If the source table had 100+ rows of data, I would like to be able to select 3 rows using something like

```
select top 3
       colA,
       colB,
       colC,
       colX
from sourceTable
where Rowid >= @RowIdVariable
```

where @RowIdVariable value is coming from another table, RowsIdFrom

```
create table RowIdsFromTable
( 
  id int Identity(1,1) Not Null,
  RowIdFrom int
)
```

I am thinking of using a cursor for this.

```
declare MyCursor cursor for
    select RowIdFrom from RowIdsFromTable order by RowIdFrom asc
Open MyCursor
```

I know my results will look something like this below for the select statement

```
sid | colA | colB | colC | colX
-------------------------
1     1      2      3      0
2     4      5      6      0
3     7      8      9      1
```

With these results, I would very much like to know how I can could insert them into my resultsTable so that

```
select *
from resultsTable
```

should look like the results below and do it in the most efficient way please :D

```
rowId | sid1 | colA1 | colB1 | colC1 | sid2 | colA2 | colB2 | colC2 | sid3 | colA3 | colB3 | colC3 | colX
1       1       1      2       3       2      4       5       6       3      7       8       9       1
```

where colX bit value belongs to the last row, as in the above example,

```
colA | colB | colC | colX
-------------------------
7      8      9      1
```

Thanks for any pointers and help :D

140213 Edit:

To give more information or to be more clear, I am needing to insert into the resultsTable the returned row because I have another table that defines all the RowId that I should be selecting from.  This table just contains the starting point RowId's.

The desired output may therefore look like below if RowIdsFromTable contained 3 values, 1, 12 and 20

```
rowId | sid1 | colA1 | colB1 | colC1 | sid2 | colA2 | colB2 | colC2 | sid3 | colA3 | colB3 | colC3 | colX
1       1      1       2       3       2      4       5       6       3      7       8       9       1
2       12     24      9       13      32     13      43      88      14     2       54      23      0
3       20     xx      xx      xx      21     xx      xx      xx      22     xx      xx      xx      1
```

where "xx" represents the integer values from the sourceTable.  Please note the order of the sid's ascending.

I attach an sql fiddle with the tables and some test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95fa8/1/0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal really is to select a finite number of rows to perform this script on, then you could use the solution below.

```
WITH Top_3_Rows_CTE AS (
SELECT Top 3 1 AS Artificial_Grouping
    ,RowID
    , colA
    , colB
    , colC
    , colX

FROM sourceTable

WHERE RowID >=2
)

, Row_Numbers_CTE AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Artificial_Grouping) AS Row_Number --Pick an order by clause that makes the most sense for your situation
    , Artificial_Grouping
    , RowID
    , ColA
    , ColB
    , ColC
    , ColX

FROM Top_3_Rows_CTE
)

SELECT DISTINCT R2.RowID AS RowID1
    , R2.ColA AS ColA1
    , R2.ColB AS ColB1
    , R2.ColC AS ColC1
    , R2.ColX AS ColX1
    , R3.RowID AS RowID2
    , R3.ColA AS ColA2
    , R3.ColB AS ColB2
    , R3.ColC AS ColC2
    , R3.ColX AS ColX2
    , R4.RowID AS RowID3
    , R4.ColA AS ColA3
    , R4.ColB AS ColB3
    , R4.ColC AS ColC3
    , R4.ColX AS ColX3

FROM Row_Numbers_CTE R1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Row_Numbers_CTE R2
        ON R2.Row_Number = 1
            AND R1.Artificial_Grouping = R2.Artificial_Grouping
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Row_Numbers_CTE R3
        ON R3.Row_Number = 2
            AND R1.Artificial_Grouping = R3.Artificial_Grouping
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Row_Numbers_CTE R4
        ON R4.Row_Number = 3
            AND R1.Artificial_Grouping = R4.Artificial_Grouping --You would create another join here for each row you want broken out into columns
```

This should be pretty fast as it starts be only selecting 3 rows and all the processing is restricted to CTEs containing no more than 3 rows. You would just add a Left Outer Join to the Row_Numbers_CTE for each additional row you want transposed into new columns.

Comment: Hi Christopher, yes, this will be for a finite number of rows so yes, this looks great.  I see that you also transpose the colX bit value across for each row and I only need it for the last row.  I'm going to have a play with your sample, thank you.  I will let you know how it goes and I like how the code reads simply.

Comment: Hi Christopher, take a look at the SQL fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af86d/4/0  It's not looking exactly right?  Null values and 3 rows instead of one?  Eventually I would like to have multiple rows in the same output table, but from different "Where" condition of RowId, select top 3
       colA,
       colB,
       colC,
       colX
from sourceTable
where Rowid >= 50, for row 2 "... where RowId >= 80" etc...  Are we missing a group by or something like that?

Comment: Ah. My bad. I hadn't thought all of that through quite as well as I needed to. Using your SQLfiddle, I was able to get the desired result using the code above (I updated my answer). I needed to create an artificial grouping in the first CTE which would allow me to correlate the top 3 rows together. You'll notice that the artificial grouping value is then perpetuated throughout the query to keep those three rows associated with one another. The updated SQLfiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af86d/9/0

Comment: Hi Christopher, not your bad at all :P  I've updated my main question to reflect more clearly my desired output.  I also have included a sqlfiddle link with your updated code and some sample data.  I'm having difficulty in figuring out how to insert the row of data into the resultsTable now.  Is that possible to do?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95fa8/3

Comment: Hi Christopher, I updated my sqlfiddle with my insert of the CTE into the the resultsTable, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddaf8/2/0  .  I'm wondering, I think of using a cursor to read from the RowIdsFromTable the id's I need to take.  Is there a way we could do to avoid using a cursor?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Work has been crazy. Unless I'm missing something, you should do the following: With CTEs as (--Script here) Insert Into TableName Select --Main query here

Comment: Hey Christopher, yes, I took a look at inserting with CTE and I have updated the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddaf8/2/0  What I've noticed, looking at the execution plan is that there is a 31% cost for the select distinct.  As in my real life situation, I actually have 30 rows and not just 3, with 9 properties/columns, therefore I'm ending up with 1 row and 270 columns.  Can you think of any way to reduce this cost and make this a little more efficient as I also have to execute this several times while inserting into the resultsTables? Thanks

Comment: David, try replacing the Distinct with Top 1. Note, Top 1 is a very different approach than Distinct, so this may not have the exact same result in your real-life application. Just make sure it does exactly what you want when you start using the real data.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for that tip, I will try this.  I've marked your answer as the answer to my question as I feel this comes as close as possible to what I am looking for and now it's time for me to play around with making your TSQL query as efficient as possible :D

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made it clear how the X bit is to be resolved (choosing a single `bit` value from `3`), so I made a choice (any 1 bit wins, otherwises its 0).

The following query should do you using `group by`. We do the following:

- use `row_number()` to assign a contiguous row id to the set
- use modulo 3 arithmetic to partition the set into groups of 3 rows, assigning each row in the group a contiguous sequence number: 0, 1 or 2.
- summarize (flatten) each group into a single row via `group by`, projecting each row within the original group into the correct columns in the summary row.

Here's the query:

```
select t.gid ,
       A1 = sum( case t.seq when 0 then A else null end ) ,
       B1 = sum( case t.seq when 0 then B else null end ) ,
       C1 = sum( case t.seq when 0 then C else null end ) ,
       A2 = sum( case t.seq when 1 then A else null end ) ,
       B2 = sum( case t.seq when 1 then B else null end ) ,
       C2 = sum( case t.seq when 1 then C else null end ) ,
       A3 = sum( case t.seq when 2 then A else null end ) ,
       B3 = sum( case t.seq when 2 then B else null end ) ,
       C3 = sum( case t.seq when 2 then C else null end ) ,
       X  = convert(bit,sign(sum(convert(int,t.X))))
from ( select * ,
              seq = ( row_number() over (order by id) - 1 ) % 3 ,
              gid = ( row_number() over (order by id) - 1 ) / 3
       from dbo.source_table
     ) t
group by t.gid
order by t.gid
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for your answer, in fact, regarding the bit number, it's just a value that should be ported over to the new table dependent on the last rows value of it.  I've also tried to simplify my problem as I actually have 30 rows to convert into 1 line with 2x bits, colX columns, colX, colY for example.  I was just thinking of using an update statement to the table after for the bit values.  I'm going to have a go and see how the modulo will work when I have 30 rows and several more columns of data.

Comment: In what I am trying to achieve and not in this simplified example is to actually have 30 rows with 6 fields each into 1 row, multiple columns.  How would the modulo handle this?