# Getting data on a single row

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports, report

I have a stored procedure that return the data as shown below. There is 3 rows of information for evey company. I am trying to design a crystal report to display the data on a single row as shown below under Desired Output.

How can this be done ?

Loc facility             ARtype days    Revenue PPD
140 Company ABC MCD 1724    4000    137.76
140 Company ABC MRA 218 8000    327.69
140 Company ABC MPD 85  7000    166.84

Desired Output
140 Company ABC MCD 1724    4000 137.76 MRA 218 8000 327.69 MPD 85 7000 166.84

Comment: I just answered this question on another thread. Check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by revenue and place your field in detail where you get individual record.

Now use the below formula.

```
Shared StringVar a;

a:=a+<<Database field>>;
```

Place the above formula beside the database filed in detail and supress

Now create another formula

```
Shared StringVar a;
a;
```

Place above formula in group footer.

Edit:

Create another formula reset

```
Shared StringVar a;
a:=" ";
```

Place this formula in group header and supress the formula as this not of user importance.

Comment: I am a bit confused. First of all, it gives error when I use Share. Secondly, when you say datbase field, you are refering to a field in the report right ? Also, what has to be supressed? Also, will this work to display the data for each company on a differnt row ?

Comment: yes it should work...it was a typo error dont use `share` use `Shared`. supress the detail and group by company to get in different row.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine for company 1. For company2, it concatenates the details for company1 and comapny 2 and so on. How do I reset the value of a, after each line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below simple steps,

1] Assuming you are putting your data in detail section, go to **Section Expert** of detail section and check the checkbox having label **Format with Multiple Columns**

2] This will print your data the way you are expecting. For additional formatting, you will find **layout** *tab* generated once you check the checkbox. In that **layout** you can set the width of detail lines as well as gaps between lines etc.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't see any change in the output.