# How to get data on a single row

Tags: t-sql

I have table called RUGS with the data below. How do I write a TSQl query to get the data as shown in Output. I am not familiar with unPIVOT

`cono   ARtype  days    Revenue PPD

140 MCD 5   1000    500

140 MRA 6   2000    600

140 MRA 7   3000    700

141 MCD 1   5000    100

141 MRA 2   6000    200

141 MRA 3   7000    300`

Result

140 MCD 5   1000    500 MRA 6 2000  600 MRA 7   3000    700

141 MCD 1   5000    100 MRA 2 6000  200 MRA 3   7000    300

Comment: How do you decide the column order? Are there always 3 records for each id? What if more or less?

Comment: yes - 3 records for very cono. The cono should appear only once for the 3 records.

Comment: You asked exactly same question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890782/getting-data-on-a-single-row  , please don't ask same question twice

Comment: That was in crystal reports.Now I need a Tsql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that every `cono` will have exactly 3 records (as stated in the comments), a `cte` with `row_number` can be used with case statements.

If any have less than three records, you will see blanks and zeroes in the results.  Any with more than three will not have all records represented.

Here is an example with `@RUGS` as a table variable:

```
declare @RUGS table (cono int, ARType char(3), [days] int, Revenue int, PPD int)

insert into @RUGS VALUES
(140,'MCD',5,1000,500)
,(140,'MRA',6,2000,600)
,(140,'MRA',7,3000,700)
,(141,'MCD',1,5000,100)
,(141,'MRA',2,6000,200)
,(141,'MRA',3,7000,300);

with cte as 
(
    select row_number() over(partition by cono order by (select 1)) as rn, * from @RUGS
)

select cono, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then ARType else '' end) as ARType1, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then days else '' end) as days1, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then Revenue else '' end) as Revenue1, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then PPD else '' end) as PPD1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then ARType else '' end) as ARType2, 
    max(case when rn = 2 then days else '' end) as days2, 
    max(case when rn = 2 then Revenue else '' end) as Revenue2, 
    max(case when rn = 2 then PPD else '' end) as PPD2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then ARType else '' end) as ARType3, 
    max(case when rn = 3 then days else '' end) as days3, 
    max(case when rn = 3 then Revenue else '' end) as Revenue3, 
    max(case when rn = 3 then PPD else '' end) as PPD3      
from cte group by cono
```